# Keras binary classificator always predict the same class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I ran into a problem while building a NN with Keras, basically the network learns to predict always the class with more instances in the training set.

I've divided my code in sections:

**Data preparation**

```
data = purchase_data.copy()
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
target_sum = 120
data.loc[data['sales'] <= target_sum, 'sales'] = False
data.loc[data['sales'] > target_sum, 'sales'] = True

print("\n\nColumn Names & formatting:\n")
for col in data.columns.values.tolist():
    if data[col].dtype == "object" or data[col].dtype == "bool":
        print("{:<30}".format(col), ":", "{:<30}".format(str(data[col].dtype)) , "Formatting to LabelEncoding")
        data[col] = labelencoder.fit_transform(data[col])
    else:
        print("{:<30}".format(col), ":", "{:<30}".format(str(data[col].dtype)) , "No formatting required.")

# Converting datetime to float
data['accessed_date'] = data['accessed_date'].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())

array = data.values 
class_column = 'sales' # The column I want to predict

X = np.delete(array, data.columns.get_loc(class_column), axis=1) # Removing class_column column
Y = array[:,data.columns.get_loc(class_column)] # Selecting class_column column
Y = Y[:, np.newaxis] # Resetting the shape value

# Normalizing the input values (excluding the class value)
scaler = preprocessing.Normalizer().fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)
```

**Splitting the dataset**

```
seed = 1
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test  = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed, shuffle = True, stratify=(Y))
```

**Neural Network**

```
tf.random.set_seed(seed)


# Building the neural network
modeldl = Sequential()

modeldl.add(Dense(64, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_normal()))
modeldl.add(Dropout(0.2))

modeldl.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=he_normal()))
modeldl.add(Dropout(0.2))

modeldl.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=he_normal()))


# Compile model
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-04)
modeldl.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['acc'])

results = modeldl.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=80, batch_size=1000, verbose=1)
```

**Confusion matrix**
At the end of the training we get this confusion matrix:

|  | Positive | Negative |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Positive | 0 (TP) | 21719 (FN) |
| Negative | 0 (FP) | 22620 (TN) |

**Questions**
How can I solve this issue?

I've tried:

- to play with hyperparameters
- to predict another column instead of 'sales'
- to resize the network
- to fix a certain learning rate
- to change the activation function
- to add/remove dropout layers

**Other info**
The dataset contains more or less 50% of the class '0' and 50% of the class '1'. I'm using [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kzmontage/e-commerce-website-logs) but I've removed the column and the rows related to returns.

Comment: This exact same issue has been asked so many times in Stack Overflow, did you search the site? Class imbalance is a very well known problem, you are not the first person to have it.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes, I read many posts before writing my own. All the points you see listed in the "Questions" section were explored thanks to other posts I found on Stack Overflow. I have been stuck for almost a week and I am about to conclude that the real problem I am experiencing is due to the dataset and my lack of experience in this area (this is my first time training a neural network)

Comment: I suggest that you take a ML course instead, Stack Overflow is a programming site, not a general ML site. Here you will only find people trying to guess what the problem is.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I am taking a ML class and our professor challenged us to train a model with Keras, he just showed us the functions and let us try. I asked here because I ran into a problem and I don't know how to solve it yet, if I find something interesting I'll update the post to help who'll have the same issue in the future.

Comment: Did you read the part where I said that Stack Overflow is for programming, not for ML issues?

Answer (score 2):

From your code there isn't any obvious mistake made. I would suggest you do to do a few things here:

- study the [EDA](https://www.kaggle.com/code/bhushanshelke69/ecommerce-logs-eda) section
- try to fit linear regression to a promising feature identified in the EDA, such as membership status, and improve your classifier by adding more features you identified as useful

Neural networks are generally used only when you have exhausted traditional statistical methods because the amount of data is very large. However, you will need to have an underlying correlation between the input and output features you want to predict.

In your case, you handle time series data and a diverse set of other inputs (such as bytes compressed), and it could be possible that there isn't any useful correlation that the network could learn in these combined features.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you:

1. If you are trying to perform classification, makes no sense to use timestamps as a feature. Timestamps are usually unique values and they may cause confussion to the model. Remove that feature. You could use month on quarter as a seasonal information feature, instead of microseconds information.
2. Try a Tree Regression method (Random Forest) to get a quick and specific information about feature relevance. It will point you where to focus for feature engineering.
3. Identify relevant features on the EDA. There is an interesting material here to visit on your dataset kaggle page: https://www.kaggle.com/code/xokent/e-commerce-website-logs-visualization